# Выбор массивов в JS по значениям переменных

Tags: javascript

Пожалуйста, подскажите как решить следующую, по-видимому простую, задачу в JS:

В JS есть ряд исходных массивов:

```
var arr1 = array(значения);
var arr2 = array(значения);
var arr3 = array(значения);
.....
var arr15 = array(значения);
```

Их можеть быть и больше т.к. их число меняется при перезагрузке страницы.

В код поступают две переменные, например:

```
var num1 = 5;
var num2 = 10;
```

Посредством какого когда можно добиться, чтобы в зависимости от значений переменных num1 и num2 выбирались соотсветсвующие массивы, т.е. в данном случае получалось так:

```
var itog_arr_1 = arr5;
var itog_arr_2 = arr10;
```

И соответственно, если переменные поступают такие:

```
var num1 = 2;
var num2 = 12;
```

тогда:

```
var itog_arr_1 = arr2;
var itog_arr_2 = arr12;
```

Comment: `var itog_arr_1 = window["arr" + num1];`

Comment: ну или двумерные массивы

Comment: @ Igor, спасибо, работает!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Храните ваши массивы в одной мапе:

```
var arrays = {
  1: [...],
  2: [...]
};
```

или в массиве:

```
var list = [[...], [...], ...];
```

Тогда и выбор по номеру/индексу будет элементарен

---

Если массивы глобальные, можно обращаться к ним, как к свойствам глобального объекта:

```
window['arr'+num];
```

Если они локальны, единственный способ взять их по индексу - eval, но я категорически рекомендую пересмотреть ваши структуры данных в этом случае.